# Positioning a fixed background image in CSS with top and right margins

Tags: css, margin, fixed

I want to have a fixed position background image that scales and I need it to have a 220px top margin and a 170px right margin so that the image is not under the navigation bars. I have come close with the following code but the right margin varies due to the percent.

```
#container_hu
{
width: 100%;
text-align: left;
background: #fff;
border: 0px solid #000000;
height:100%;
padding-top:260px;
min-width:1100px;
background:url(../images/bg_image.jpg) no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-position: 78%  220px;
background-size:25%;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4):

You can use CSS3's `background-clip` property to force clip the background to within the allowed content area. i.e. you can specify a padding to your DIV (to cover the nav bars etc..) and specify the `background-clip` property to `content-box` to achieve this. Example CSS below:

```
#container_hu {

    /* this forces the bg to be rendered only within allowed content area (CSS3) */
    background-clip: content-box;
    background-image: url("your_image.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    /* this forces the bg to stretch with the container (CSS3) */
    background-size: 100% 100%;

    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;

    /* specify the top/left pixels to cover your nav-bar etc. */
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: IE8 and below not supported. FYI

Comment: Yeah. background-clip is CSS3 only so wont work in IE8 and below. Since your question already mentioned background-size (which is CSS3 and doesn't work in IE8 and below), i thought you're ok with a CSS3 only solution.

Comment: Another issue I have with this is the background does not move with the scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

So to start off its 170px right margin and then a percentage from what you describe.

I would consider 2 options:

1. Redo your entire layout in ems for all dimensions, margins, puddings etc. with a base unit on body. That way you may have more of a chance of things lining up. (in essence I'm saying start with ems, scale up in ems, as %age will not work)
2. You could also start with pixels and scale up in pixels but you'll need JavaScript to do the calculation and apply the new margin right onResize.